# How to create radio button dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to display a list of data stored in array and against each data I want to put a yes and no radio button. I have generated radio button dynamically, but from all the radio buttons I can only select one at a time, but it should be like, for each data I can select either yes or no. Please help as I am new to JavaScript.

```js
function displayData()
{
 var data=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwi'];
 var output="";
 var output2="";
 var dataList;
 
 for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
 {
  dataList=data[i];
  output+= '<input type="checkbox" value='+dataList+' name="box2">'  + '   ' + dataList+'   '+'<br><br>';
  output2+= 'yes:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="box2">'+'no:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="box2">'+'<br><br>';
  document.getElementById("dataList").innerHTML=output;
  document.getElementById("radioBtn").innerHTML=output2;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="displayData()">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><div id="dataList"> </div></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><div id="radioBtn"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use checkboxes ?

Comment: I have used checkbox for some different purpose and I want the user to be able to select only one input for each data either yes or no.

Comment: Each iteration in the for loop should generate two radio buttons with the same unique for the two name, you can for example append the i variable to the name: 'yes:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="box2-' + i + '">' Respectively do this for the "no" radio control as well.

Comment: They all have the same name. And why do you change the `innerHTML` in instead of after the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign diffrent name to each row of checkbox. Please check below code

```
function displayData()
    {
        var data=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwi'];
        var output="";
        var output2="";
        var dataList;

        for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
        {
            dataList=data[i];
            output+= '<input type="checkbox" value='+dataList+' name="box2'+i+'">'  + '   ' + dataList+'   '+'<br><br>';
            output2+= 'yes:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="box2'+i+'">'+'no:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="box2'+i+'">'+'<br><br>';
            document.getElementById("dataList").innerHTML=output;
            document.getElementById("radioBtn").innerHTML=output2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I got it now, Thank you very much @Pramod

Answer (score 1):

This is not what a radio button is for, at least, in your implementation.

You must use a radio group name for each of your yes/no choices.

if you change the `name="box2"` HTML property by a dynamic name, for example `name="box' + i + '"'`, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding radio buttons make sure to add button names dynamically

`<input type="radio" value="yes" name="'+data[i]+'">'`

Demo

```js
function displayData()
{
 var data=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwi'];
 var output="";
 var output2="";
 var dataList;
 
 for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
 {
  dataList=data[i];
  output+= '<input type="checkbox" value='+dataList+' name="box2">'  + '   ' + dataList+'   '+'<br><br>';
  output2+= 'yes:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="'+data[i]+'">'+'no:<input type="radio" value="yes" name="'+data[i]+'">'+'<br><br>';
  document.getElementById("dataList").innerHTML=output;
  document.getElementById("radioBtn").innerHTML=output2;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="displayData()">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><div id="dataList"> </div></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><div id="radioBtn"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```